# How to prevent double click on button

Tags: swift, uibutton, action

how to prevent double click on button in case of http request
i've tried this code but in double click my request is sended twice to the server. please give me solution

```
 @IBAction func btnSendForgetPwdAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

  sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

  if checkIfFieldsAreFilledInforgetPwd(){
     self.showProgressView()
     var requestParams: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
     requestParams["email"] = textFieldEmailForgetPWD.text

     let url = Constants.URLs.PREFIX_URL+Constants.URLs.FORGET_PASSWORD

     DataHelper.sharedInstance.alamofireManager().request(url, method: .post, parameters: requestParams, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        self.hideProgressView()

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(let JSON):
           if let response = JSON as? NSDictionary{
              print("JSON  \(response)")
              if   let isSuccess = response.object(forKey: "success") as? Bool{

              }
              // i have some code here


  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { [weak sender] timer in

     sender?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  })
```

Comment: have you tried isEnabled ?

Comment: no i m just tried the code in my question

Comment: first, edit your question as suggested, so other people can understand or they will down vote you for bad formatting, 2nd i will provide an answer as a suggestion to try in this case

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem - need to see how you're making the your call to the server.

Comment: **Note**: Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift

Comment: When you use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` you throw away type information. Use Swift `Dictionary` or `Array` containing the actual types you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making an asynchronous webservice call, you need to wait until that is complete until re-enabling your button. *Don't* use a timer, as you don't know how long the call will take to complete.

Without seeing your server call I can't give a complete answer, but you should be doing something like this…

```
@IBAction func btnBackAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    Webservice().loadData { result in  // Your async server call 

        sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        // Handle the result

       // performSegue goes here if you need to wait until your server call is complete  
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController", sender: nil) 
    }
}
```

Comment: i delete the timer and i respect your solution its work